# I have an array of percentages I want to find the average to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, average, reduce

I'm using React JS, and I'm trying to find the average of this array:

```
[
    "75.0%",
    "50.0%",
    "66.66666666666666%",
    "66.66666666666666%",
    "33.33333333333333%",
    "58.333333333333336%",
    "50.0%",
    "66.66666666666666%",
    "41.66666666666667%",
    "75.0%",
    "41.66666666666667%",
    "50.0%",
    "50.0%",
    "72.72727272727273%"
]
```

Here's my current code:

```
const percentCorrects = [
    "75.0%",
    "50.0%",
    "66.66666666666666%",
    "66.66666666666666%",
    "33.33333333333333%",
    "58.333333333333336%",
    "50.0%",
    "66.66666666666666%",
    "41.66666666666667%",
    "75.0%",
    "41.66666666666667%",
    "50.0%",
    "50.0%",
    "72.72727272727273%"
]

const sum = percentCorrects.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
   return accumulator + currentValue
 }, 0);

const averaged = sum / percentCorrects.length;
console.log("averaged", averaged);
```

Right now, my console shows

```
averaged NaN
```

Which I looked it up: "The NaN global property is a value representing Not-A-Number"

How do you recommend I fix my code?
I want to be able to display an averaged percentage on my UI, for example: "Average Percent Correct: 48%"

Please let me know how I could fix my code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your percentages are not numbers, they're strings.

Try console logging your value `sum` and you'll see it'll look like `"75.0%50.0%66.66..."`. This is because in JavaScript the `+` operator will concatenate strings.

Then when you divide a string by a number, you'll get a NaN. (Try `console.log("foo"/2)`)

You'll need to first convert those percentages in to numbers.

The [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function can do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your array contains strings, so the `reduce` is concatenating strings, not adding numbers, you can use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to fix this:

```js
const percentCorrects = [
    "75.0%",
    "50.0%",
    "66.66666666666666%",
    "66.66666666666666%",
    "33.33333333333333%",
    "58.333333333333336%",
    "50.0%",
    "66.66666666666666%",
    "41.66666666666667%",
    "75.0%",
    "41.66666666666667%",
    "50.0%",
    "50.0%",
    "72.72727272727273%"
]

const sum = percentCorrects.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
   return accumulator + parseFloat(currentValue)
 }, 0);

const averaged = sum / percentCorrects.length;
console.log("averaged", averaged);
```

And while you don't have to trim the `%` from the strings when using [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) (it won't consider them when parsing the string), you could use [`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) in order to trim those percentage signs off. So your return statement would look like this:

```
return accumulator + parseFloat(currentValue.slice(0, -1))
```